# Unknown attribute despite having initialized it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am completely new to rails and I ran into a problem while I try to define an association between models. To be specific, I am trying to create a relationship between task and category but It ran into the error when I try to connect them `category.tasks << task1`.
The Error:

```
C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activemodel-7.0.4/lib/active_model/attribute.rb:211:in `with_value_from_database': can't write unknown attribute `category_id` (ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError)

          raise ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError, "can't write unknown attribute `#{name}`"
          ^^^^^
```

task1 attribute:

```
t.string :name
t.text :description
t.integer :position
t.boolean :completed
t.timestamps
```

category attribute:

```
t.string :name
t.timestamps
```

the pre-set the connection between task and catogory

```
class AddCategoryIdtoTask < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  def change
    add_column(:tasks, :category_id, :integer, index:true)
  end
end
```

```
class Task < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :category, optional: true
end
```

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :tasks
end
```

When I appendix `task1` into `category.tasks` , would it not update the `category_id` to match?
I hope some passerby could look into this error that I feel like I am obviously missing something

Comment: Could it be that you forgot to run the migration? ;)

Comment: Also you don't "initialize" database backed attributes in ActiveRecord. It reads the schema directly from the database and creates setters, getters and type metadata in your model when it loads the class. That migration won't do anything unless you actually run it. The correct way to setup a foreign key is with `add_reference(:tasks, :category)` - you'll very likely get a type error if you use `add_column(:tasks, :category_id, :integer)` as Rails uses `:big_int` as the default type for primary keys.

Comment: sire @max , I have tried your suggestion but the console returned a similar error message. Though, I am grateful for your help. And btw, I check the migration and it is up so definitely running.

Comment: That sounds like a case of  programmer error. There is nothing wrong with the code here except that you're using the wrong type for the column. Make sure the migration is run and that you have reloaded any classes if you're doing this from the console. It could also be that the new error message is completely unrelated to the original problem.

Comment: Also ensure that you're running the migration in the same environment that the code is running in. This is an extremely common problem and its just simple human error 99.9999999% of the time.